# Launch script in a new window on schedule, as admin

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I would like to schedule the execution of a PowerShell script, with the following criteria:

- Run the PowerShell script in a visible PowerShell terminal window (I want the PowerShell terminal to popup on-screen so the user can see that the script is executed)
- Run the PowerShell script on schedule (at some time)
- Run the script as admin
- Run the script even if no-one is logged in to the computer

Ideally I'd schedule the task from command line, but that's not really a requirement.

How can I manage this?

Comment: Is the admin account the same user who should see the terminal?

Comment: Yes. (ignore this text I just have to write something so the comment is not too long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Crate scheduled task:

[image]

- Chose admin account for task execution.
- Select option `Run whether user is logged on or not`

### Configure time schedule:

[image]

### Create action:

[image]

- Enter ***PowerShell*** in `Program/scrip` field
- In Add arguments field enter `-File` argument with path to script and `-ExecutionPolicy` argument with `bypass` value. (`-ExecutionPolicy bypass`)